# How to get Adjusted R-Square value as variable?

Tags: r, regression

I am attempting to get the Adjusted R-Square value in R (the programming language) and store it as a variable. I am not sure how to accomplish this.

I can see the R-Square value if I call:

```
summary(lm(x~y))
```

Along with the rest of the data, but how do I get the specific value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`summary( lm(y~x) )$adj.r.squared`

Comment: Also, it is probably worth exploring the str() command (short for structure). for example str(summary(lm(x~y)))

Answer (score 4):

CrockGill's answer is correct, but I also think it is important you know *how* to find the code to get these variables.

You can use the attributes function like this:

```
attributes(summary(lm(x~y)))
```

This returns:

```
$names
 [1] "call"          "terms"         "residuals"     "coefficients"  "aliased"       "sigma"        
 [7] "df"            "r.squared"     "adj.r.squared" "fstatistic"    "cov.unscaled" 

$class
[1] "summary.lm"
```

From this you can find that $adj.r.squared is what you need to type after summary(lm(x~y)).

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow is the better place to ask this kind of question, but briefly,

```
x <- 1:5
y <- jitter(x * 2) + rnorm(5)
fit <- lm(y~x)
names(fit)
str(fit) # more detail
```

For the coefficients,

```
fit$coef
```

will print them.  The commands `str` and `names` can help you figure a lot of stuff out.

Comment: Adjusted $R^2$ is actually a component of `summary(fit)`, so `names(fit)` will not be helpful, but `names(summary(fit))` would be.